Compare 2 metrics and give Distinct Count of INNER JOIN
I wanted to compare two metrics in Grafana.

missing_users_hosts{Site=~"$Site"}
active_users{Site=~"$Site"}

Now I wanted to find the Distinct Count of label name EmailID like INNER JOIN
I used the following codes but no luck
 missing_users_hosts{Site=~"$Site"} * on(EmailID) active_users{Site=~"$Site"}

and
 count(count by (EmailID) (missing_users_hosts{Site=~"$Site"}) * on (EmailID) group_left() count by (EmailID) (active_users{Site=~"$Site"}))

I wanted to see the count using Stat Visualization in Grafana and I use Prometheus Data Source.

And? What is not working? How you want to "join" metrics? what labels are present in both of them?
